# How to get value of Element ID from dynamic table

Tags: javascript

My question here is how to get the element id value from dynamic input text with [$i] from this
`<input type='text' class='form-control num-only 'id='price[$i]' />`

full Code:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p id="demo">Create Invoice</p>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="crud_table">
         <tr>
            <th class="" >#</th>
            <th class="" >Product</th>
            <th class="" >Item Price</th>
            <th class="" >Quantity</th>
            <th class="" >inStore</th>
            <th class="" >New Quantity</th>
            <th class="" >Total</th>
         </tr>
         <tbody>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) { 
           echo" 
            <tr>
               <td align='center'><?php echo $i;?></td>
               <td><input type='text' class='form-control ' value=''   id='itemname[$i]' /></td>
               <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only '     id='price[$i]' /></td>
               <td><input type='number' class='form-control num-only'  maxlength='5' id='quantity[$i]' onchange='kofta(this)'/></td>
               <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only'   maxlength='50' id='inStore[$i]'  onchange='kofta()'/></td>
               <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only'   maxlength='10' id='newq[$i] ' onchange='kofta()'/></td>
               <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only'   maxlength='50' id='total[$i]' readonly /></td>
            </tr> ";
             } ?>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="text" id="total" readonly value="0">
       
      <script>
         function kofta(){
         var rate= document.getElementById("price").value;
         var q1=document.getElementById("quantity").value
         var total= rate * q1;
         document.getElementById("total").value=total;
         }
         
      </script>
```

How i can get the value ?? so i can calculate the values
total = price * quantity
total of all rows in total input text

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use `data-attribute` instead ?

like:

```js
let totalinput = document.getElementById("total");
function kofta() {
  var rate = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var q1 = document.getElementById("quantity").value
  var total = rate * q1;
  totalinput.value = total;
}
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-number]');
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', SumAll);
});

function SumAll() {
  let counter = 0;
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    counter+=+input.value; 
  });
  totalinput.value = counter;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p id="demo">Create Invoice</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="crud_table">
    <tr>
      <th class="">#</th>
      <th class="">Product</th>
      <th class="">Item Price</th>
      <th class="">Quantity</th>
      <th class="">inStore</th>
      <th class="">New Quantity</th>
      <th class="">Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align='center'>1</td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control ' value='' id='itemname1' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only ' id='price1' data-number /></td>
        <td><input type='number' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='5' id='quantity1' onchange='kofta(this)' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='50' id='inStore1' onchange='kofta()' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='10' id='newq1' onchange='kofta()' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='50' id='total1' readonly /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align='center'>2</td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control ' value='' id='itemname2' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only ' id='price2' data-number /></td>
        <td><input type='number' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='5' id='quantity2' onchange='kofta(this)' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='50' id='inStore2' onchange='kofta()' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='10' id='newq2 ' onchange='kofta()' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control num-only' maxlength='50' id='total2' readonly /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="text" id="total" readonly value="0">
```

Everytime you change input price the total will update.

**What i did?**

1. Add `data-number` to input price
2. Use `addEventListener` to all inputs price (with `data-number`)
3. Create a function for sum all value from inputs.
4. Update total value

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you mean, maybe this will help?

```
var prices = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="price"]');
```

This get all elements whose id starts with "price".

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that php appends the content of `$1` to the text you put it behind. So, if `$1` contains 1, as indicated by the loop, the id of the input would be `price1`. To get the value of that field you'd need to use `document.getElementById("price1").value`.

If you want to get the value of all created fields, you'd need to loop over all inputs with the id `priceX`, where X is the number. You can check what numbers are appended to the ID if you open that page in your browser and inspect the element.

edit1:

You could try to use the `previousSibling` property.

```
function kofta(quantityField) {
    let rate = quantityField.previousSibling.value,
        quantity = quantityField.value;
}
```

Comment: yes i want get element dynamically from current selected row

Comment: You mean when someone changes the quantity? Or how does the selection work?

Comment: yes when someone changes the quantity in current row

Comment: I edited the answer, could you try it out?